# How to select row if datatable column picker is also active

Tags: r, shiny, datatables, dt

I have a datatable. I want the user to be able to pick columns from the table (for various functions). I also want the user to be able to check some boxes. However, when the user checks a box in my application the column is also selected. I dont want this to happen. How can I stop this

**ui.R**

```
ui<-fluidPage(
  # box(width=12,
  h3(strong("My picker"),align="center"),
  hr(),
  # column(6,offset = 6,
  HTML('<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">'),
  actionButton(inputId = "Del_row_head",label = "Delete selected rows"),
  HTML('</div>'),
  # ),

  #column(12,dataTableOutput("Main_table")),
  tags$script(HTML('$(document).on("click", "input", function () {
                       var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName("row_selected");
                       var checkboxesChecked = [];
                       for (var i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i++) {
                       if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
                       checkboxesChecked.push(checkboxes[i].value);
                       }
                       }
                       Shiny.onInputChange("checked_rows",checkboxesChecked);
                       })')),
  tags$script("$(document).on('click', '#Main_table button', function () {
                  Shiny.onInputChange('lastClickId',this.id);
                  Shiny.onInputChange('lastClick', Math.random())
                  });"),



  dashboardPage(

    dashboardHeader(title = 'My shiny'),

    dashboardSidebar(),
      dashboardBody( DT::dataTableOutput("endotable")))
  )




RV <- reactiveValues(mtcars)
```

**server.R**

```
server <- function(input, output) {
output$endotable = DT::renderDT({
  if (!is.null(mtcars)) {  

    mtcars[["Select"]]<-paste0('<input type="checkbox" name="row_selected" value="Row',1:nrow(mtcars),'"><br>')

    mtcars[["Actions"]]<-
      paste0('
                 <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary delete" id=delete_',1:nrow(mtcars),'>Delete</button>
                 </div>
                 ')
  }

 datatable(mtcars,escape=F,options = list(scrollX = TRUE,pageLength = 5),selection = list(target = 'column'))

},selection = list(target = 'column'),escape=F,options = list(scrollX = TRUE,pageLength = 5))

observeEvent(input$Del_row_head,{
  row_to_del=as.numeric(gsub("Row","",input$checked_rows))

  mtcars=mtcars[-row_to_del]}
)




observeEvent(input$lastClick,
             {
               if (input$lastClickId%like%"delete")
               {
                 row_to_del=as.numeric(gsub("delete_","",input$lastClickId))
                 RV$data=RV$data[-row_to_del]
               }
               else if (input$lastClickId%like%"modify")
               {
                 showModal(modal_modify)
               }
             }
)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `selection` to `"none"`; we will "manually" define the selection behavior with the help of the `Select` extension and a callback. Enable this extension, use the option `select = "api"`, and attribute a class `notselectable` to columns 12 and 13 ('Select' and 'Actions'):

```
datatable(mtcars, escape=FALSE, callback = JS(callback), 
          extensions = "Select", selection = "none",
          options = list(
            scrollX = TRUE, 
            pageLength = 5,
            columnDefs = list(
              list(className = "notselectable", targets = c(12,13))
            ),
            select = "api"))
```

Now the callback:

```
callback <- c(
  "table.on('click', 'tbody td', function(){",
  "  // if the column is already selected, deselect it:",
  "  if(table.column(this, {selected: true}).length){",
  "    table.column(this).deselect();",
  "  // otherwise, select the column unless there's the class 'notselectable':",
  "  } else if(!$(this).hasClass('notselectable')){",
  "    table.column(this).select();",
  "  }",
  "});"
)
```

[image]

---

## EDIT

New question raised in a comment:

> The table in the real app is reactive and new columns can be added so
>   that the targets = c(12,13) will stop the table being shown. How can I
>   define the last two columns as being not selectable rather than a
>   specific column number?

Use this callback:

```
callback <- c(
  "var ncols = table.columns().count();",
  "table.on('click', 'tbody td', function(){",
  "  // if the column is selected, deselect it:",
  "  if(table.column(this, {selected: true}).length){",
  "    table.column(this).deselect();",
  "  // otherwise, select the column unless it's among the last two columns:",
  "  } else if([ncols-1, ncols-2].indexOf(table.column(this).index()) === -1){",
  "    table.column(this).select();",
  "  }",
  "});"
)
```

And no need to set a class to the last two columns:

```
datatable(mtcars, escape=FALSE, callback = JS(callback), 
          extensions = "Select", selection = "none",
          options = list(
            scrollX = TRUE, 
            pageLength = 5,
            select = "api"))
```

---

## EDIT 2

To get the indices of the selected columns in Shiny:

```
callback <- c(
  "var ncols = table.columns().count();",
  "var tbl = table.table().node();",
  "var tblID = $(tbl).closest('.datatables').attr('id');",
  "table.on('click', 'tbody td', function(){",
  "  // if the column is selected, deselect it:",
  "  if(table.column(this, {selected: true}).length){",
  "    table.column(this).deselect();",
  "  // otherwise, select the column unless it's among the last two columns:",
  "  } else if([ncols-1, ncols-2].indexOf(table.column(this).index()) === -1){",
  "    table.column(this).select();",
  "  }",
  "  // send selected columns to Shiny",
  "  var indexes = table.columns({selected:true}).indexes();",
  "  var indices = Array(indexes.length);",
  "  for(var i = 0; i < indices.length; ++i){",
  "    indices[i] = indexes[i];",
  "  }",
  "  Shiny.setInputValue(tblID + '_columns_selected', indices);",
  "});"
)
```

Then the indices of the selected columns are in `input$endotable_columns_selected` *if there are the row names in the table*; if there's no row name, the indices are `input$endotable_columns_selected + 1`.

---

## EDIT 3

Here is a cleaner way to delete the rows:

```
callback <- c(
  "var ncols = table.columns().count();",
  "var tbl = table.table().node();",
  "var tblID = $(tbl).closest('.datatables').attr('id');",
  "table.on('click', 'tbody td', function(){",
  "  // if the column is selected, deselect it:",
  "  if(table.column(this, {selected: true}).length){",
  "    table.column(this).deselect();",
  "  // otherwise, select the column unless it's among the last two columns:",
  "  } else if([ncols-2, ncols-3].indexOf(table.column(this).index()) === -1){",
  "    table.column(this).select();",
  "  }",
  "  // send selected columns to Shiny",
  "  var indexes = table.columns({selected:true}).indexes();",
  "  var indices = Array(indexes.length);",
  "  for(var i = 0; i < indices.length; ++i){",
  "    indices[i] = indexes[i];",
  "  }",
  "  Shiny.setInputValue(tblID + '_columns_selected', indices);",
  "});",
  "/* ---------------------------------------------------------- */",
  "// Handler to delete rows",
  "Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('deleteHandler', function(rowIDs){",
  "  for(var i = 0; i < rowIDs.length; ++i){",
  "    deleteRow(rowIDs[i]);",
  "  }",
  "});"
)

js <- paste0(
  c(
    "function deleteRow(rowID){",
    "  var table = $('#endotable').find('table').DataTable();",
    "  var nrows = table.rows().count();",
    "  for(var i=0; i < nrows; ++i){",
    "    if(table.row(i).id() == rowID){",
    "      table.row(i).remove().draw(false);",
    "      break;",
    "    }",
    "  }",
    "}"
  ), 
  collapse = "\n"
)

ui <- fluidPage(

  tags$head(tags$script(HTML(js))),

  h3(strong("My picker"),align="center"),
  hr(),
  HTML('<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">'),
  actionButton(inputId = "Del_row_head",label = "Delete selected rows"),
  HTML('</div>'),
  tags$script(HTML('$(document).on("click", "input", function () {
                   var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName("row_selected");
                   var checkboxesChecked = [];
                   for (var i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i++) {
                   if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
                   checkboxesChecked.push(checkboxes[i].value);
                   }
                   }
                   Shiny.onInputChange("checked_rows",checkboxesChecked);
                   })')),
  # tags$script("$(document).on('click', '#Main_table button', function () {
  #             Shiny.onInputChange('lastClickId',this.id);
  #             Shiny.onInputChange('lastClick', Math.random())
  #             });"),

  dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = 'My shiny'),
    dashboardSidebar(),
    dashboardBody( DT::dataTableOutput("endotable")))
)

mtcars[["Select"]] <- 
  paste0('<input type="checkbox" name="row_selected" value="row_',1:nrow(mtcars),'"><br>')

mtcars[["Actions"]] <-
  paste0('
               <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary delete" id=delete_',1:nrow(mtcars),'>Delete</button>
               </div>
               ')

mtcars[["ROWID"]] <- paste0("row_", 1:nrow(mtcars))

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  RV <- reactiveValues(data = mtcars)

  # observe({
  #   print(input$endotable_columns_selected)
  # })

  output$endotable = DT::renderDT({

    datatable(RV$data, escape=FALSE, callback = JS(callback), 
              extensions = "Select", selection = "none",
              options = list(
                scrollX = TRUE, 
                pageLength = 5,
                select = "api",
                rowId = JS(sprintf("function(data){return data[%d];}", ncol(RV$data))),
                columnDefs = list(
                  list(visible = FALSE, targets = -1)
                )
              )
    )

  }, server = FALSE)

  observeEvent(input[["Del_row_head"]], {
    session$sendCustomMessage("deleteHandler", as.list(input$checked_rows))
  })

  # observeEvent(input$Del_row_head,{
  #   row_to_del <- as.numeric(gsub("Row","",input$checked_rows))
  #   RV$data <- RV$data[-row_to_del, ]
  # })
  # 
  # observeEvent(input$lastClick,
  #              {
  #                if (input$lastClickId%like%"delete")
  #                {
  #                  row_to_del=as.numeric(gsub("delete_","",input$lastClickId))
  #                  RV$data=RV$data[-row_to_del]
  #                }
  #                else if (input$lastClickId%like%"modify")
  #                {
  #                  showModal(modal_modify)
  #                }
  #              }
  # )
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: OK. Thanks @StephaneLaurent. The table in the real app is reactive and new columns can be added so that the targets = c(12,13) will stop the table being shown. How can I define the last two columns as being not selectable rather than a specific column number?

Comment: @SebastianZeki `list(className = "notselectable", targets = c(-1,-2))` works, but I'm not sure this is fine if you add columns. Give it a try.

Comment: @SebastianZeki See my edit. Perhaps this solution is better.

Comment: I just realised that the table now does not let me use the value returned from input$endotable_columns_selected in other functions.  Why is this and how to allow?

Comment: @SebastianZeki Ah yes, we have to manually define that too. See my second edit.

Comment: Thanks @StephaneLaurent. Does the callback overrise any other javascript in the shiny script? In the actual app the checkboxes in each row of the datatable allow the user to select which row they want to delete. However now the delete button deletes the first two columns rather than the selected row. I've added the observeEvent. Please let me know if you think this needs a separate question.

Comment: @SebastianZeki Are you deleting with `RV$data[-row_to_del]` ? This code deletes a column. This should be `RV$data[-row_to_del, ]`. Your code is not reproducible : `RV` is not defined in the server. So I can't try. Please edit your code so that I can try.

Comment: My apologies @StephaneLaurent. The RV was defined after the UI but I have now changed this as I guess it is only the table that needs to be reactive in my case. The code did work with the checkboxes deleting rows previously so I guess Im wondering if the tags$script(HTML(' line should be added to the callback or whether the callback is suppressing it somehow?

Comment: I pasted my script with your javascript into the callback. I also moved the comma as suggested. Now it deletes one row and one column whereas I just want to delete one row per checkbox selection

Comment: OK all sorted now. Thanks for showing me the callback. Now time to learn more javascript in shiny

Comment: @SebastianZeki I think the way you use to delete the rows is not correct. Imagine you delete the second row. Then the third row becomes the second row, and the checkbox with value `Row3` does not correspond to the third row anymore. See my third edit, this is a clean way to delete the rows. One advantage is that it does not re-render the table when you delete some rows. The selected columns remain selected.